# How to make dynamically view by get ID (PK) in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I want to make dynamically view when button ('lihat berkas') is clicked as this screenshoot :
**strong text**
[image: The Table with 'lihat berkas' button]

Then i want every button display dynamically as the row data from table, like this :
**The description if clik button as the row data**
[image: The description if clik button as the row data]

So what code i am must  write?
Thanks before master, sorry i'm still newbie...

Comment: Are need code for if click button, then display full details in another page based on user id ? this is correct ?

Comment: Yes allright, do you have solution?

Comment: Yes. Set link of button with last segment is user id and get user details based on user id and display in another page